# Getting error while updating and adding new pod ios

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting error while anding new pod file to my existing file.
Then i run command to update but it showing the following errro.

The `iPhonePoker [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'.`
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `iPhonePoker [AdHoc]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined

in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.adhoc.xcconfig'.`

`This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation`

- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
  COG-MAC-003:PT

Please check this and let me know where i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

In your project go to project target Build Settings>Other linker flags>double click . 
Add $(inherited)

Comment: It fixes my issue earlier, can you clean and try to reinstall pod.

Comment: Okay can you just tell me how to remove and reinstall the pods because i am new to ios

Comment: Add $(inherited) to header search path and check i think it will fix it. And for removing the all the pod, go to your pod file delete all the pods (for example pod 'AFNetworking') and run pod install command it will remove all the pods, after that add the pod you required and again run pod install command